# How to detect network isReachable using phonegap (1.8.0)

Tags: android, cordova

I am using the phonegap1.8.0 and I want to detect if the net is available and then if I could reach it. At the phonegap [doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/0.9.6/phonegap_network_network.md.html#Network) expose the following api

```
navigator.network.isReachable('www.facebook.com', reachCallBack, {});
```

however, I got the

```
Console(4820): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isReachable' at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:71
```

The code is:

```
    function netIsAvailable()
{
    var reachCallBack = function (reachability)
    {

        var networkState = reachability.code || reachability;

        var states = {};
        states[NetworkStatus.NOT_REACHABLE]                      = 'No network connection';
        states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_CARRIER_DATA_NETWORK] = 'Carrier data connection';
        states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_WIFI_NETWORK]         = 'WiFi connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);

    };
    alert(  navigator.onLine );
    navigator.network.isReachable('www.facebook.com', reachCallBack, {});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `isReachable` function is deprecated since v1, and now you have to use `connection` or network events to perform the similar logic.

[Connection information](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)

[online/offline events](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online)

For more detail refer to this [group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phonegap/Ez4nwwZaDXw/eJxjsxwP39IJ)

Comment: Group post link is now broken.

Comment: You just needed to remove the `.` at the end, @lunchmeat317